# Toggle multiple elements using JavaScript function parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show/hide a div depending on which button is clicked. I tried doing this using parameters of the javascript function but I'm guessing I'm doing it all wrong, so please help.

Here's the HTML I have:

```
<div id="div1">
Content of div1</div>
<div id="div2">
Content of div2</div>

<button id="button" onclick="showhide(x)">Toggle div1</button>

<button id="button" onclick="showhide(y)">Toggle div2</button>
```

And here's what I've got so far, JS-wise:

```
<script>
 function showhide(x,y)
 {
       var div x = "div1";
       var div y = "div2";
       var div = document.getElementById(x);
       var div = document.getElementById(y);

if (div.style.display !== "none") {
    div.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    div.style.display = "block";
}
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here is the HTML code :
<div id="div1">
 Content of div1
</div>
<div id="div2">
  Content of div2
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="showhide('div1')">Toggle div1</button>
<button id="button" onclick="showhide('div2')">Toggle div2</button>

Here is the javascript code :

<script type="text/javascript" >
 function showhide(toggleID){
   var toggleDiv = document.getElementById(toggleID);
   if(toggleDiv.style.display != "none"){
    toggleDiv.style.display = 'none';
   }else{
    toggleDiv.style.display = 'block';
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a javascript function which has 2 parameters, and in your HTML you are only sending 1.
What you can do is the following:

In the HTML onclick at the buttons:

```
<button id="button" onclick="showhide('div1')">Toggle div1</button>
<button id="button" onclick="showhide('div2')">Toggle div2</button>
```

And the javascript function only needs 1 parameter:

```
function showhide(divElement)
{

   var div = document.getElementById(divElement);

   if (div.style.display !== "none") {
     div.style.display = "none";
   }
   else {
      div.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it should be single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Well that looks a lot better, but I can't get it to work (yes I changed the " to '). Don't laugh but I'm trying to use it on a WordPress site, perhaps that's reason enough. What I don't understand is how the script can activate when there is no mentioning of the specific DIVs in the script. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not right:

```
var div x = "div1";
```

You can't have space in it:

```
var div_x = "div1";
```

You can actually remove both lines and leave it like this:

```
function showhide(x,y)
 {
       var div = document.getElementById(x);
       var div2 = document.getElementById(y);

       if (div.style.display !== "none") {
           div.style.display = "none";
       }
       else {
           div.style.display = "block";
       }

       if (div2.style.display !== "none") {
           div2.style.display = "none";
       }
       else {
           div2.style.display = "block";
       }
 }
```

And call it with:

```
showhide("div1", "div2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
<button id="button" onclick="showhide(x,'')">Toggle div1</button>

<button id="button" onclick="showhide('',y)">Toggle div2</button>
```

And change this:

```
var div = document.getElementById(x);
var div = document.getElementById(y);
```

To this:

```
var div = document.getElementById(x && y); //if x returns x else y
```